# get self. values from class B to variables in function in class A, and then change the variable values without changing self. values in class B

Tags: python-3.x, copy, deep-copy

I want to use values in class B(self.array_B) and assign them to variables(array_A) in class A while executing "step" function in class A. However, after I change the variable values(array_A) to be zeros in class A, the values of (self.array_B) are also changed to zeros which is very awkward. (self.array_B) should remain the same after I change the variable values in class A. Is there any way to solve this?

```
import numpy as np

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.B = B()

    def step(self):
        print("array_B:", self.B.array_B)
        array_A = np.zeros((2, 2))
        array_A = self.B.array_B

        print("array_A:", array_A)
        for i in range(2):
            for j in range(2):
                array_A[i][j] = 0
        print("------------------")
        print("after changing variable value:array_B:", self.B.array_B)
        print("after changing variable value:array_A:", array_A)
        return "done"

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        self.array_B = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]

def test_main():
    env = A()
    s = env.step()
    print(s)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_main()
```

output:

```
array_B: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
array_A: [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
------------------
after changing variable value:array_B: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
after changing variable value:array_A: [[0, 0], [0, 0]]
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning the list here:

```
array_A = self.B.array_B
```

you are only copying a reference to the original list. So `A.array_A` and `B.array_B` actually refer to the same list, and any changes to the list will be reflected in both references.

You can copy the list itself instead by using:

```
array_A = self.B.array_B.copy()
```

Now `A.Array_A` and `B.Array_B` refer to different lists, and can be changed independently.

If the list contains mutable objects itself, a simple copy() is not enough. Both lists will still contain references to the same mutable objects inside. In this case, a deepcopy() is needed, which also makes a copy of all elements inside the list:

```
import copy
array_A = copy.deepcopy(self.B.array_B)
```

This is quite an expensive operation and should only be used when needed.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. The results remain the same.

Comment: Please check the deepcopy part of my answer. You need a deepcopy since your list contains lists itself.

Comment: Learned a lesson it is an expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

just assign a copy of `arrayB` to `arrayA`:

```
array_A = self.B.array_B.copy()
```

This is because while `arrayB` is assigned to `arrayA`, it is the address of `arrayB` not the actual value of it is assigned to the name `arrayA`. Therefore, just use the method `copy()` to create a copy of `arrayB` and then assign.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution** here would be to use [deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/copy.html)

**Why does this happen?**
Lists are [mutable objects](https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/), which mean that array_A still points to the same object in memory that array_B.

If you had worked with a list of immutable values (like integers), a simple

`array_A = list(self.B.array_B)`

or even

`array_A = self.B.array_B[:]`

would do the trick, because it would force python to instantiate a new list.

But here, the items of array_B also are lists, so if you did that:

```
array_A = list(self.B.array_B)
array_A[0][0] = 3
print(self.B.array_B[0][0] == 3) # >> would print True
```